# HttpStatus 406 при попытке вернуть JSON

Tags: java, json, rest

Есть контроллер.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "send")
public class MessageSendController {
```

В нём есть метод:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/mail",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Report> mail(@RequestPart("data") MailMessageDto dto,
                                       @RequestPart(name = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments) {
        return universalMessageService.send(dto.attach(dto, attachments), mailHandler).map(d -> new ResponseEntity<>(d, HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(ResponseEntityUtils.createHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK));
    }
```

Контроллер должен принимать некие данные и возвращать отчёт в JSON. Данные он принимает отлично, но отчёты не отдаёт.

Пишет:

> HTTP Status 406 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The resource identified by this request is only capable of
>   generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to
>   the request "accept" headers.

Зависимости:

```
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.3'
```

WebConfig:

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = jacksonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter);
        converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    }
```

ResponseEntityUtils:

```
public static HttpHeaders createHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        return headers;
    }
```

Comment: Что возвращает этот код `ResponseEntityUtils.createHeaders()`?

Comment: добавил в вопрос. только в случае успешной обработки метода он не задействуется.

Comment: Ошибка 406 означает, что в заголовке `accept` запроса нет того типа, который указан в заголовке `content-type` ответа. Соответственно, стоит глянуть что в заголовках запроса и что в заголовках ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом.

Тот паршивец, который писал этот код, который мне посчастливилось ревьюить, забыл добавить геттеры классу Report. В результате, сериалайзеру нечего было сериализовывать и вылетало `InvalidDefinitionException`, который я не видел, а видел только 406. Для того, чтобы докопаться до сути, мне пришлось возвращать `String` и получать его через `ObjectMapper`.